# PDF viewer AcroPDF Error

Tags: pdf, vb6, adobe, viewer

I've just added an AcroPDF plug in in my legacy vb6 application. I was able to add it in by adding a component called :

```
Adobe Acrobat 7.0 Browser Control Type Library
```

and a reference called :

```
Adobe Acrobat Browser Control Type LIbrary 1.0
```

I called this control faxView. this control has it's own form so basically on form load I specify the .src like this...

```
faxView.src = 'a particular directory
```

Now what happens is sometimes, the pdf document is displayed correctly, I mean bells and whistles, all the zoom in buttons, print button everything looks beautiful. Other times I get an while screen with an empty message box, looks like this...

[image]
Now the interesting this is that I'll get this error message a few times, however after the first timet hat the fax loads properly, it loads fine every single time. I can view tens of faxes as long as I don't restart my application. Any one have any idea what this could be?

Comment: Frustrating... is there an Adobe log file? Perhaps check windows event logs?

Comment: @DaveInCaz that would definitely help but i'm not sure since this is a plug in but i'll check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suprisingly the issue with the PDF viewer was only happening when I ran it out of IDE. Once i created an .exe file and ran it, everything was okay. Still not sure what the issue is but as long as it runs properly for the user, it's all set.